# App not Starter after deploy on Tomcat 7.0.90 Server: Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

I am using Maven with server 7.0.90 and after generating the .war file successfully I am getting the following error after doing the deploy in Tomcat.When I attempt to run my project on Tomcat I get these exceptions.
I'm using Maven 3.5.2 with Tomcat Server 7.0.90.

I already applied in my pom file some solutions that I found in the forum, but the problems continue.

**Catalina.log:**

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.90\webapps\testapp-004.001.17.00.war
mar 17, 2019 8:20:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
mar 17, 2019 8:20:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
mar 17, 2019 8:20:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Context [/testapp-004.001.17.00] startup failed due to previous errors
mar 17, 2019 8:20:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

**Localhost.log:**

```
mar 17, 2019 8:20:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class mapfre.srv.RepositoryDeployer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mapfre.srv.RepositoryDeployer.contextInitialized(RepositoryDeployer.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1815)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1514)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:198)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2555)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2544)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**My pom.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>004.001.17.00</version>
  <name>Tomcat Deploy Test</name>
  <!-- TestApp Config Properties -->
  <properties>
    <dir.files.properties>src/test/properties</dir.files.properties>
  </properties>
    <!-- Nexus Repos Config -->
   <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository> 
    <repository>
        <id>nexus_testapp</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/repository/myrep-testapp-releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
   <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <url>${releases.repo.url}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <url>${snapshots.repo.url}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
   </distributionManagement>
    <!-- Build Config -->   
    <build>
    <filters>
        <filter>${dir.files.properties}/${build.profile.id}/deploy.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
   <!-- Plugins -->
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>${dir.files.properties}/build.properties</file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution> 
            </executions> 
            <configuration>
                <altDeploymentRepository>nexus_testapp::default::http://localhost:8080/nexus/repository/myrep-testapp-releases/</altDeploymentRepository>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>default-deploy</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>nexus_testapp</serverId>
                <altDeploymentRepository>nexus_testapp::default::http://localhost:8080/nexus/repository/myrep-testapp-releases/</altDeploymentRepository>
                <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>WebContent/properties</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>properties</targetPath>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
            <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>sonar</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>sonar</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8085/manager/text</url>
                <server>tomcat</server>
                <path>/tronweb</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   <!-- Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.0-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.testapp.dgtp.v2.lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>dfc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.testapp.dgtp.v2.lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>dfcbase</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.testapp.dgtp.cosym.arqos.env.lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.testapp.dgtp.cosym.arqos.env.lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.testapp.testapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>testframework</artifactId>
      <version>004.007.00.00</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.90</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <!-- Profile -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DESMX</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>DESMX</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.testapp.testapp.testclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>trn</artifactId>
                    <version>004.001.20.00</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
</project>
```

**My Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>TestApp Server</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>testapp.srv.ServidorCIMSStartUp</listener-class> 
    </listener> -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>testapp.srv.RepositoryDeployer</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- <servlet>
    <servlet-name>invoker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVCreaZipFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVCreaZipFile</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVCreaZipFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVCreaZipFile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVAdmon</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVAdmon</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVAdmon</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVAdmon</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVCorreo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVCorreo</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVCorreo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVCorreo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVInvertedProxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVInvertedProxy</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVInvertedProxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVInvertedProxy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVJspool</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVJspool</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVJspool</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVJspool</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVLst</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVLst</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVLst</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVLst</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVRep</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVRep</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVRep</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVRep</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVTronWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVTronWeb</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVTronWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVTronWeb</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVUtilidades</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVUtilidades</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVUtilidades</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVUtilidades</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVWebServices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVWebServices</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVWebServices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVWebServices</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.utl.Genoma</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.utl.Genoma</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.utl.Genoma</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.utl.Genoma</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVAyuda</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testapp.srv.SVAyuda</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testapp.srv.SVAyuda</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVAyuda</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>TestApp Admin URLs</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>TestApp Admin URLs</web-resource-name>
        <!-- <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVCreaZipFile</url-pattern> -->
        <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVAdmon</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/tw_labels.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TWError.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TWMensaje.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TWDepurar.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TWStack.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/TWTrazas.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/blank.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/encabezado.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/index.htm</url-pattern>
        <!-- <url-pattern>/instalar.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/install.html</url-pattern> -->
        <url-pattern>/menu.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/menuUS.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/tw_etiquetas.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>testappadmin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>TestApp user URLs</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>TestApp user URLs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/testapp.srv.SVCreaZipFile</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/instalar.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/install.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>testappuser</role-name>
        <role-name>testappadmin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- Defines the Login Configuration for this Application -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Area de acceso restringido</realm-name>
</login-config>

<!--Security roles referenced by this web application -->
<security-role>
    <role-name>testappuser</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>testappadmin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

** My RepositoryDeployer.java lines 47-100:**

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final ServletContextEvent event = arg0;
        try {
            //Load TestApp Properties
            String rootPath = event.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            File contextDir = new File(rootPath);
            String contextName = contextDir.getName();

            //Init logger
            configureLogger(contextName);
            logger = LogFactory.getLog(RepositoryDeployer.class);
            logger.info("Publishing TestApp Repository...");
            logger.info("Context name: "+contextName);

            TLComun.cargarPropiedades("0", rootPath, contextName);

            //Check Property for the Repository Path
            String repositoryDir = TLComun.getRRS();
            File repFile=new File(repositoryDir);
            String[] numSegments=repFile.toURI().normalize().getPath().split("/");

            if (numSegments.length<3||!repFile.isAbsolute()){
                logger.warn("Incorrect Path "+repositoryDir+". It must have at least 2 segments and it can't be relative. i.e. /ap/testapp or C:\\ap\\testapp");
                repositoryDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + contextName;
                TLComun.setRRS(repositoryDir);
                logger.warn("Temporal directory "+repositoryDir+" is used instead");
            }

            //Jar extraction
            String jarUrl = TLComun.getClientLocation();
            logger.debug("TestApp Client JAR Location: " + jarUrl);
            logger.debug("TestApp Repository Location: " + repositoryDir);
            logger.debug("Extracting Repository...");
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            extractJar(jarUrl, repositoryDir);
            logger.info("Repository Extracted Successfully in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1) + " ms");

            //TestApp Labels generation
            logger.debug("Generating Labels...");
            t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
            boolean res = GeneradorTextosHTTP.generarTodasEtiquetas();
            if (res){
                logger.info("Labels Generated Successfully in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1) + " ms");
            }else{
                logger.warn("WARNING: Labels not generated");
            }
            logger.info("Context "+contextName+" startup in "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0)+" ms");
        } catch (Throwable e) {//Avoid starting if something wrong happens
            System.err.println("TestApp Server context not started due to errors. Check if war contains the client jar.\n" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            logger.error("TestApp Server context not started due to errors. Check if war contains the client jar.\n" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help and guidance.

Comment: show the code for `mapfre.srv.RepositoryDeployer.contextInitialized(RepositoryDeployer.java:99)`

Comment: Hi Scary, below the feedback get from the code:

Comment: Seems strange. Line 99 is your log. Have you control that your logger is not null?

Comment: Yes, I need to make sure I'm getting the messages from the log.